# Sling - AEM sling:members from a new collection

Tags: java, aem, sling

I've recently entered the world of AEM and sling (api).  What I'm trying to do is write Java code to get the sling:members and its properties sling:resources for a new collection I created in the touch.  I'm able to reference the collection properties with a ResourceResolver.resolve(path).  The sling:members show up as { ....}.  Do I have to do a separate ResourceResolver?

```
String path="/content/dam/collections/m/fafdsfdaf/my_collection";
Resource resourceMember = resourceResolver.resolve(path+"/sling:members");
ValueMap metaData = resourceMember.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
String[] slingResources = metaData.get("sling:resources", new String[0]);
```

Am I totally off the mark?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get the members of the collection is to use the ResourceCollection API.  To do this you obtain the resource which points to the collection then adapt it to a `ResourceCollection`.  From there you call `getResources()` which returns you an iterator over the members.

```
Resource r = resourceResolver.getResource("/content/dam/collections/m/fafdsfdaf/my_collection");
ResourceCollection collection = r.adaptTo(ResourceCollection.class);
Iterator<Resource> it = collection.getResources();
while(it.hasNext()) {
   Resource p = it.next();
    %><%= p.getPath() %><%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is the correct way to do this and is working.